# UML use case diagram "cafeteria system" validation

Tags: uml, system, use-case

I've written a script to make a cafeteria system at college. I need to know whether my diagram is correct, especially the shares of the operations.

- The student selects one of the restaurants available in the cafeteria.
- The student selects the item you want with the possibility of adding some ingredients to the item and receive the sellers.
- The student pays to the seller. The delivery of a request is included, an update to the store at the moment the student is paid.
- The seller's issue the invoice to the student and includes an addition to the account of exports and imports of the restaurant.
- Administrator for the restaurant When you want to add new item, the sellers are notified of the new item added.
- Administrator records attendance and absence of sellers.

[image]

Comment: "I drew the painting" by the hell, what sort of painting do you want to do ? Have you read some articles about UML schemas ? At least to know what are you doing.

Comment: If your question is about the picture, not the script, then this is probably not the right forum. Otherwise, better post the script instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Use correct naming for use cases: predicate, subject (, object).
- Do not use include/extend as it's simply mistaken for functional decomposition, which is plain wrong.
- Synthesize function descriptions to extract the added value hidden behind those descriptions and make them use cases (single added values the system under consideration delivers to its actors).
- It's ok to indicate primary and secondary actors by using directed associations. However, this in no standard, but a convention and needs to be explained in separate modeling rules.
- Your `saller` should likely be `Seller`. Note the upper case first char too (also wrong with `Student`).
- With little effort your diagram could have been uncluttered!